# Passing an integer to a python script using bash

Tags: python, bash

I would like to automate a python script that runs in a bash while loop

The python script takes in 2 scientific values but for the sake of simplicity lets just say

```
main(a,b):
c = a + b
# write c to file.. python isn't the issue 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    firstInt = sys.argv[1]
    secondInt = sys.argv[2]
    main(firstInt, secondInt)
```

The bash script will run this indefinitely until a keyboard interrupt. The real question is, how do I pass a number to this script?
currently I have the bash script below

```
#!/bin/bash
numberOne=30e3
numberTwo=1.03e6

while true
do
    echo "press CTR:+Z to stop"
    python script.py "${numberOne}" "${numberTwo}"
```

I've tried to type it in just how i would on the command line, but I'm unsuccessful. Any ideas would greatly be appreciated.

running on:
CentOS 7.8

Comment: Really? Ignoring a lot of typing errors, like missing `def`, wrong indentation, missing `done` and missing `import sys` [your code as presented works](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/DarkgreenWavyNewsaggregator#main.sh). So please post an [MCVE]. Please note that CTRL+Z usually _stops_ the execution of the program - it doe _not terminate_ the process. Ususally CTRL+C is used to terminate a foreground process.

Comment: The python code was there more as a brief example to show that i'm using the method sys.argv to read off the command line. I apologize for not placing a reproducible example, the problem is how do I use bash to pass a variable to that method as if I were typing it myself.

Comment: Parsing `sys.argv` directly may work (and, despite the question appears to in this case); however, it's almost always better to use tooling to do it for you. [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), for example, is in the standard library and can handle a lot of the lifting, checking that an argument makes sense as an integer, for example. There are additional tools on Pypi that can provide even more power and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Just calling the function works for me. Not sure what you aiming for here, could you provide your real code?

**Python:**

```
def main(a, b):
    print(a,b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    firstInt = sys.argv[1]
    secondInt = sys.argv[2]
    main(firstInt, secondInt)
```

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
numberOne=30e3
numberTwo=1.03e6

while true
do
    python3 test.py "${numberOne}" "${numberTwo}"
done
```

**Output:**

```
>>> bash test.sh
30e3 1.03e6
30e3 1.03e6
....
```

Comment: The code itself is python 2.7.5 running in a cshell. I can't really post the full code due to company policy. Thanks for the response